# How to get all package displayed only in apps screen

Tags: android, filter, apk, system

I tried to get all installed apk by :

```
public ArrayList<InfoObject> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<InfoObject> res = new ArrayList<InfoObject>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        Log.v("PACKAGE GET","" +p.packageName + "flags => " +  p.applicationInfo.flags);
       /* if ((p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
            continue ;
        }*/
        InfoObject newInfo = new InfoObject();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res;
}
```

It works fine !!

But without ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM , I show only my installed apk (facebook, skype)

with ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM , I show all apk (facebook, skype) and all system apk.

My issue is that from system apk how to filter only application are exist on my apps menu.

for example :
I needed to get Album Camera facebook ...
and No devicemonitor, InputDevices, Memoire apps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer to my question :)

we can get all appications by getLaunchIntentForPackage that returns a good intent to launch a front-door activity in a package.

***if( mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName) != null )***

Thanks